# How do I get item from localstorage immediately after page loads in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

This is my storage:
[image: localstorage]
I get `selectedResultIsLCC` with value `"true"`

This is my script:

```js
computed: {
  isLCC() {
    return localStorage.getItem("selectedResultIsLCC") === "true";
  },
},
```

This is my template:

```js
<div>
    <div
      v-if="isLCC"
      @click="sendTicketRequest"
    >
        Book Now (LCC)
    </div>
    <div
      v-else
      @click="sendBookRequest"
      >
        Book Now (Non-LCC)
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have to hard refresh before I see v-if in template which returns true in my storage.

Please how do I go about this, how can I get the item in my storage immediately the page loads.

Comment: Use a lifecycle hook like mounted etc

Comment: If you are not getting expected result as per `@Hans Felix Ramos` answer then looks like its a local storage value setting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `created` or `mounted` lifecycle and it's better store variables in vue data:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isLCC: false
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.isLCC = localStorage.getItem("selectedResultIsLCC") === "true";
        },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: i still need to refresh before seeig results

Comment: when you store localstorage?